# Android Studio, Firebase W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Tags: android, json, google-maps, firebase

[image: Screen Shot [![][1]]

Right now I working on to tracking bus in campus.

As you can see screenshot. There are two bus right now. so when click icon bus. it will show distance and duration arrival time but it not show anything.

I retrieve location from Firebase.

I'm using java, Android studio and Firebase.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
```

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLJPo.jpg)

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na2yR.jpg)

```
mDriver = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
.title(rider.getEmail())
.snippet("DISTANCE : " +getDistanceInfo(currentUser,driver)+" KM ")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));

private double getDistanceInfo(Location currentUser, Location driver) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            double dist = 0.00 ;


            String latDriver = Double.toString(driver.getLatitude());


            String lngDriver = Double.toString(driver.getLongitude());



            String latCurrent = Double.toString(currentUser.getLatitude());
            String lngCurrent = Double.toString(currentUser.getLatitude());


            try {

                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+"&origin="+latDriver + "," + lngDriver  + "&destination=" +latCurrent + "," + lngCurrent+ "&mode=driving&sensor=false+"+"key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_browser_key);


                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject;


            try {


                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);

                    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");

                    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                    JSONObject distance= steps.getJSONObject("distance");

                    Log.i("Distance", distance.toString());
                    dist = Double.parseDouble(distance.getString("text").replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]", ""));



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (dist);
        }
```

Error show in logcat

[Image Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aie7D.jpg)

Comment: It looks like your routes array is empty. Can you post the response you are getting from the directions api?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the "routes" array you have has length 0. So there is no items in the array and you are trying to access the object at index 1, so it's throwing an error that the array is empty so there is no index 1 in the array.

Try logging the whole JSON body to console and check whether the "route" key has objects inside it.